# Layer Stack in Erdas Using Python

Tags: python

I'm Trying to layer stack images of Band1,Band2 and Band 3 in Erdas using Python.Can anyone suggest how to do it in python.

```
from imagine import modeler
imagePath = "'C:\\Desktop\\Erdas_Script\\New folder'"
outputPathStack = "'C:\\Desktop\\Erdas_Script\\New folder'"
m = modeler.Model()
ri1 = m.RasterInput("BAND2.tif")
ri2 = m.RasterInput("BAND3.tif")
ri3 = m.RasterInput("BAND4.tif")
ri4 = m.RasterInput("BAND5.tif")
StackBands = m.StackLayers(ri1, ri2, ri3, ri4)
ro = m.RasterOutput(StackBands, outputPathStack + "_stack.img")                               
m.Execute()
```

It throws error

```
RuntimeError: Intergraph::SpatialModeler::Operator::Execute failed
Intergraph::SpatialModeler::Operator::Execute failed
Intergraph::SpatialModeler::Operator::Execute failed
Intergraph::SpatialModeler::Operator::SetErrorMessage failed
Spatial Model failed in Raster Input.  Error: Could not open raster image: BAND2.tif.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set a variable called imagePath to the folder that holds the images.

You need to use this in your raster input

```
ri1 = m.RasterInput(imagePath + "\\BAND2.tif")
ri2 = m.RasterInput(imagePath + "\\BAND3.tif")
```

etc

Now the script can access the images.

Also change your raster output to

```
ro = m.RasterOutput(StackBands, outputPathStack + "\\_stack.img")
```

This will allow the output to be placed within the New Folder directory. You might want to place a descriptive name in front of the _stack.img. At the moment the file name will be _stack.img

You can find a similar workflow [here](https://imgsblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/13/using-python-to-run-spatial-models-unzipping-landsat-8-and-stacking-layers/), the code isn't displayed the best but should help with what you want to achieve.